# how to update the data to main memory?

Tags: java, synchronized, java-memory-model

```
            while (keepRunning) {
                if (n.getCount() <= 5 && n.getCount() > 0) {
                    n.consume();
                    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()
                            + "consumed an apple," + n.getCount() + " apple(s) left");////here is 5

                }
```

`n.consume()`has changed the count (count is 4),but `n.getCount()` is still 5.
How to update the data to main memory so that n.getCount can get the updated `count`?

```
public class ThreadDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Apple n = new Apple();

        Thread a1 = new Thread(new Producer(n), "Producer");
        Thread a2 = new Thread(new Consumer(n), "Consumer");
        a1.start();
        try{
            Thread.sleep(1000) ;
        }catch(InterruptedException e){
            e.printStackTrace() ;
        }
        a2.start();
    }

}

class Producer implements Runnable {
    Apple n;

    public Producer(Apple n) {
        this.n = n;
    }

    volatile boolean keepRunning = true;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            while (keepRunning) {
                if (n.getCount() < 5) {
                    n.produce();
                    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()
                            + " produced an apple，" + n.getCount() + " apple(s) left");
                }
                if (n.getCount() >= 5) {
                    keepRunning = false;
                }
                Thread.yield();
            }
            if (n.getCount() < 5) {
                keepRunning = true;

            }
        }

    }
}

class Consumer implements Runnable {
    Apple n;

    public Consumer(Apple n) {
        this.n = n;
    }

    volatile boolean keepRunning = true;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            while (keepRunning) {
                if (n.getCount() <= 5 && n.getCount() > 0) {
                    n.consume();
                    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()
                            + "consumed an apple," + n.getCount() + " apple(s) left");////here is 5

                }
                if (n.getCount() <= 0) {
                    keepRunning = false;
                }

                Thread.yield();
            }
            if (n.getCount() > 0) {
                keepRunning = true;
            }
        }

    }

}

class Apple {
    private int count = 0;

    public int getCount() {
        return count;
    }

    public synchronized void produce() {
        this.count++;

        try {
            Thread.sleep(100);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public synchronized void consume() {
        this.count--;//here is 4
    }

}
```

Comment: Take a look at [AtomicInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html), as it does exactly, what you are implementing on your own as `Apple`. In essence, your Apple class isn't threadsafe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to synchronize *all* accesses to the `count` variable, including reads. In your case, you need to synchronize `getCount()`:

```
public synchronized int getCount() {
    return count;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Mark the count variable in Apple as volatile. This shall enforce JVM to read this variable from main memory and override the cache